# Nested dictionary skips inner content while sent to a PHP webserver as JSON using Python 3.0 (Requests)

Tags: php, json, python-3.x, xampp, python-requests

I have a large python dictionary, which is sent out as a JSON in a POST request using the py requests library to a web service which accepts incoming JSONs (XAMPP/PHP set up in localhost).

When I receive the transmitted JSON data through the POST request, PHP always gives the output as array, and not as a serialized JSON string.
Secondly, nested elements are missing from the data captured on PHP end.
I am using the following snip to do the job.

Python code :

```
import json
import requests
dummy_data = {
    "param1": "ABCDEF",
    "param2": {
        "0": "inner_data_0",
        "1": "inner_data_1"
    },
    "param3": {
        "very_big_text_key_1": {
            "inner_key_1": "inner_value_1",
            "inner_key_2": ["very_large_string_item_as_inner_value_2"],
            "inner_key_3": "inner_value_3"
        },
        "very_big_text_key_2": {
            "inner_key_1": "inner_value_1",
            "inner_key_2": ["very_large_string_item_as_inner_value_2"], 
            "inner_key_3": "inner_value_3"
        }
    }
}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'accept' : 'application/json'}
r = requests.post("http://localhost/test/data.php", params = (dummy_data), headers = headers)
    print (r.text)
```

Also tried with :

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

Both give the same output as below:

```
*Hello World!<br/>Printing GET array ...<br/>array(4) {
  ["param1"]=>
  string(6) "ABCDEF"
  ["param2"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["param3"]=>
  string(19) "very_big_text_key_2"
  ["param4"]=>
  string(6) "GHIJKL"
}
<br/>Printing POST array ...<br/>array(0) {
}*
```

I used json and data as parameters to "requests".

```
r = requests.post("http://localhost/test/data.php", json = (dummy_data), headers = headers)
```

and

```
r = requests.post("http://localhost/test/data.php", data = (dummy_data), headers = headers)
```

Output is as below :

```
*Hello World!<br/>Printing GET array ...<br/>array(0) {
}
<br/>Printing POST array ...<br/>array(0) {
}*
```

I am accepting data as follows in PHP code:

```
<?php
print "Hello World!";
echo "<br/>";
print "Printing GET array ...";
echo "<br/>";
var_dump($_GET);
echo "<br/>";
print "Printing POST array ...";
echo "<br/>";
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

The inner text doesn't seem to be appearing in any of the scenarios. I have tried to implement some solutions as suggested by members of stackoverflow. But still i am facing the above mentioned issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is now resolved. The resolution happend after consideration of the following points:

1. JSON passed by Python is not de-serialized by default, by PHP and has to be serialized, after inspection of "Content-type" header.
2. Once de-serialized, the passed JSON content was then used for further processing.

Hence the key to solve the problem was, to check the content-length, and content-type headers. If content-length was found greater than 0 and content type was application/json, the incoming JSON can be de-serialized using json_decode().

The code snips for PHP and Python, using which the following was accomplished is as below:

On the Python side:

```
    import json
    import requests
    dummy_data = {
        "param1": "ABCDEF",
        "param2": {
            "0": "inner_data_0",
            "1": "inner_data_1"
        },
        "param3": {
            "very_big_text_key_1": {
                "inner_key_1": "inner_value_1",
                "inner_key_2": ["very_large_string_item_as_inner_value_2"],
                "inner_key_3": "inner_value_3"
            },
            "very_big_text_key_2": {
                "inner_key_1": "inner_value_1",
                "inner_key_2": ["very_large_string_item_as_inner_value_2"], 
                "inner_key_3": "inner_value_3"
            }
        }
    }
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    r = requests.post("http://localhost/test/data.php", data = json.dumps(dummy_data), headers=headers)
print (r.text)
```

On the PHP side:

```
...

    if(@$_SERVER["CONTENT_LENGTH"] > 0){
        $contentType = $_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"];
        if($contentType == "application/json"){
            $decoded_data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
        }
        else{
            echo "Incoming data is not a JSON!";
        }

        return $decoded_data;
    }
```